# How to call method name of controller form angular resources

Tags: angularjs

```
  angular.module('commom.services')
    .factory("userMaintainenceService",
      ["$resource","appSettings",userMaintainenceService]);

    function userMaintainenceService($resource,appSettings){
      return $resource(appSettings.serverPath+"dbu/User",{},
      {
        Create:{method:'POST'}
      });
    };
```

Here "dbu" is folder in htdocs and "User" is controller in need to call "userDetails" method in my `userMaintainenceService.query(......)`.

How can we do this ??

Comment: Please review [ask]. You haven't identified a specific problem and it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: here User is the controller and in there i have different methods and i want to call particular method from angular controller, suppose i have 2 method UserDetails and SingleDetails which both are get method

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to create different methods for your services, you should return a service with these two methods like so:

```
angular.module('commom.services')
  .factory("userMaintainenceService",
    ["$resource","appSettings",userMaintainenceService]);

function userMaintainenceService($resource,appSettings){
  return {
    userDetails: function (userId) {
      // retrieve logic here
    },
    singleDetails: function (userId) {
      // retrieve logic here
    }
  };
};
```

And you will be able to call the service like this:

```
var userDetails = userMaintainenceService.userDetails(102);
```

And this:

```
var singleDetails = userMaintainenceService.singleDetails(102);
```

**UPDATE 1**

For information about ngResource usage, checkou [Angularjs ngResource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: can you give me the example of retrieving logic???

appSettings.serverPath+"dbu/User

here appSettings.serverPath gives me my server location "http:localhost/" and "dbu/User" is combined with it so please send me  how to get data, 

for example im using 
userMaintainenceService.query(function(data){ }
 in my controller to retrive data

Comment: Retrieving logic is another topic, you can checkout the ngResource docs wich you are already using.